# Show Chart with no Table

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I'm trying to generate a Jasper Report using DynamicJasper which is just a chart, with no table appearing above it. There doesn't seem to be a method for hiding a column or for suppressing the table. What are my options for generating just a chart? I would be open to a solution that does not use DynamicJasper, just the JasperReports java API.

```
public void go() throws ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException, JRException {
    super();

    final AbstractColumn areas = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("area", String.class.getName())
            .setTitle("Area")
            .setWidth(30)
            .build();

    final AbstractColumn exercises = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("exercises", Integer.class.getName())
            .setTitle("Exercises")
            .setWidth(30)
            .build();

    final DynamicReportBuilder reportBuilder = new DynamicReportBuilder();
    reportBuilder.addColumn(areas);
    reportBuilder.addColumn(exercises);
    reportBuilder.setUseFullPageWidth(true);

    final GroupBuilder groupBuilder = new GroupBuilder();
    groupBuilder.setCriteriaColumn((PropertyColumn) areas);
    groupBuilder.setGroupLayout(GroupLayout.EMPTY);
    final DJGroup group = groupBuilder.build();

    reportBuilder.addGroup(group);
    reportBuilder.addChart(this.chart((PropertyColumn) areas, exercises));

    final DynamicReport dynamicReport = reportBuilder.build();
    final JasperPrint jasperPrint =
            DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(
                    dynamicReport,
                    new ClassicLayoutManager(),
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.getData()));

    /* PDF */
    final JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("/tmp/my.pdf"));
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate about your problem some screenshots would be nice

Comment: can you attach screenshots on what is happening and what is required ? Also, have you tried using IReports, it works with JasperReports java API. Didn't understand your problem, so can't provide a solution yet in IReports.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have this problem the same, if you have the solution, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `DynamicJasper` is no must for you, you could try it with the [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) library.
I only did some few tests with both, but I found the `DynamicReports` much more easier to use.

Example code from my tests back then, a report with chart only (or uncomment the `.columns` section to get the columns back):

```
    // First simple test
    public static void createDynamicReportTest1()
    {
        StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style().bold();
        StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        StyleBuilder columnTitleStyle = stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)
                .setBorder(stl.pen1Point())
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        FontBuilder boldFont = stl.fontArialBold().setFontSize(12);

        // title,     field name     data type
        TextColumnBuilder<String> itemColumn = col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType());
        TextColumnBuilder<Integer> quantityColumn = col.column("Quantity", "quantity", type.integerType());
        TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> unitPriceColumn = col.column("Unit price", "unitprice", type.bigDecimalType());
        //price = unitPrice * quantity
        TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> priceColumn = unitPriceColumn.multiply(quantityColumn).setTitle("Price");
        PercentageColumnBuilder pricePercColumn = col.percentageColumn("Price %", priceColumn);
        TextColumnBuilder<Integer> rowNumberColumn = col.reportRowNumberColumn("No.")
                //sets the fixed width of a column, width = 2 * character width
                .setFixedColumns(2)
                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

         AbstractBaseChartBuilder chart = cht.barChart()
                .setTitle("Bar chart")
                //.setTitleFont(boldFont)
                .setCategory(itemColumn)
                .series(
                        cht.serie(quantityColumn))
                .setCategoryAxisFormat(
                        cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Item"));

        try {
            report()//create new report design
                    .setColumnTitleStyle(columnTitleStyle)
                    .highlightDetailEvenRows()
//                    .columns(//add columns
//                            rowNumberColumn, itemColumn, quantityColumn, unitPriceColumn, priceColumn, pricePercColumn)
                    .title(cmp.text("Getting started").setStyle(boldCenteredStyle))//shows report title
                    .summary(chart)
                    .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY().setStyle(boldCenteredStyle))//shows number of page at page footer
                    .setDataSource(createDRDataSource())//set datasource
                    .show();//create and show report
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     public static JRDataSource createDRDataSource() {
        DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "quantity", "unitprice");
        dataSource.add("Notebook", 1, new BigDecimal(500));
        dataSource.add("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(30));
        dataSource.add("DVD", 1, new BigDecimal(28));
        dataSource.add("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(32));
        dataSource.add("Book", 3, new BigDecimal(11));
        dataSource.add("Book", 1, new BigDecimal(15));
        dataSource.add("Book", 5, new BigDecimal(10));
        dataSource.add("Book", 8, new BigDecimal(9));
        return dataSource;
    }
```

For more examples have a look here:
[dynamicreports.org examples](http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/examples-overview)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `addColumn` use `addField`. Thanks to [Petter Friberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140981/how-to-hide-datatable-when-add-chart-in-dynamic-jasper#comment58004217_35140981) for this comment

Comment: Seems like a comment I made on one of your questions? : ), so I hope your answer is in good faith...

Comment: Ok, (thanks for adding attribution) now consider to improve the answer, show some what you did so it get easier to understand and maybe you will even have my upvote

Comment: If you manage to create your own post (explaining why) you are free to remove the attribution if you like

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to share my solution after I spent hours trying to figure out a solution to this.

Unfortunately, the above 2 answers did not work for me while using DynamicJasper 5.1.0. DynamicReports seems to be no longer maintained and the link is broken, and simply using addField instead of addColumn resulted in the unhelpful "duplicate declaration of parameter: dataset_null_chart" error - which seems to be related to having duplicate charts despite the fact that I was only using a single chart. (That being said, I'd love to hear if/how someone overcame these issues using DynamicJasper 5.1.x)

So I came up with the following solution - create a `LayoutManager` that does not render the table:

```
public class NoTableLayoutManager extends ClassicLayoutManager {
    @Override
    protected List<AbstractColumn> getVisibleColumns() {
        return new ArrayList<>(); // hide all columns
    }
}
```

Then use this when you generate your `JasperPrint` object:

```
JasperPrint print = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(report, new NoTableLayoutManager(), data);
```

This worked perfectly for my simple scenario of creating a stacked bar chart without a table. I haven't tried more complex reports while hiding the table, so I don't know if this will work in every situation, but it should work in the scenario you asked about, at least in DynamicJasper 5.1.0.