# Dynamic Jasper Report Pie Chart

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, pie-chart, dynamic-jasper

```
    AbstractColumn columnBranch = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty("branch", String.class.getName())
        .setTitle("Branch").setWidth(new Integer(85)).build();
    AbstractColumn columnAmount = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty("amount", Float.class.getName())
            .build();


    drb.addColumn(columnBranch);
    drb.addColumn(columnAmount);        
    drb.setUseFullPageWidth(true);



    PropertyColumn pc = (PropertyColumn) ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty("branch", String.class.getName()).build();
    DJChart djChart = new DJPieChartBuilder()
            // chart
            .setX(10).setY(10).setWidth(210).setHeight(150).setCentered(false).setBackColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
            .setShowLegend(true).setPosition(DJChartOptions.POSITION_FOOTER).setTitle(new StringExpression() {
                public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
                    return variables.get("group_state_name");
                }
            }).setTitleColor(Color.DARK_GRAY).setTitleFont(Font.ARIAL_BIG_BOLD).setSubtitle("subtitle")
            .setSubtitleColor(Color.DARK_GRAY).setSubtitleFont(Font.COURIER_NEW_BIG_BOLD)
            .setLegendColor(Color.DARK_GRAY).setLegendFont(Font.COURIER_NEW_MEDIUM_BOLD)
            .setLegendBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE).setLegendPosition(DJChartOptions.EDGE_BOTTOM)
            .setTitlePosition(DJChartOptions.EDGE_TOP).setLineStyle(DJChartOptions.LINE_STYLE_DOTTED)
            .setLineWidth(1).setLineColor(Color.DARK_GRAY).setPadding(5)
            // dataset
            .setKey(pc)
            .addSerie(ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty("amount", Float.class.getName()).build())
            // plot
            .setCircular(true).build();
    drb.addChart(djChart);
```

How to generate chart without having to generate the columns using Dynamic Jasper reports? 
and without using the abstract column builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly,
use `addField` instead of `addColumn`

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102680/show-chart-with-no-table#answer-35156935) original answer.